# Printing database query results in AS3

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

new-ish to PHP. Attempting to create a highscore table in Flash, I've got my game linked to the database and can send scores to it no problem. I can also retrieve them but the problem lies in the output.

My PHP code for retrieving the data and outputting it:

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");
if ($_POST['systemCall'] == "getScores"){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,5";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $counter = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($counter > 0){
        while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $name = $data["name"];
            $correct = $data["correct"];
            $time = $data["time"];
            $score = $data["score"];
            print "systemResult=$name\t\t\t$correct\t\t$time\t\t$score\n\n\n";
        }
    } else {
        print "systemResult=Error.";
    }
}
?>
```

Flash & AS3 are receiving the output and I've got it displaying on my game where I want it, the problem is the 'systemResult=' appears at the start of all outputs but the first one. So the high score table is something along the lines of:

```
name                  correct    time    score
alice                 19/20      38s     2182
systemResult=bob      17/20      68s     1827
systemResult=charlie  15/20      55s     1722
```

I know I could probably remove this with string manipulation but I wanna do this properly - am I going the right way about outputting the data, and if not, what's the right way to go?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are retrieving the data and using the `systemResult` item.  If so, changing the code to the following should do the trick.

```
if ($counter > 0){
    print "systemResult=";
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $name = $data["name"];
        $correct = $data["correct"];
        $time = $data["time"];
        $score = $data["score"];
        print "$name\t\t\t$correct\t\t$time\t\t$score\n\n\n";
    }
} else {
    print "systemResult=Error.";
}
```